# Query select with inner join 3 tables and where clause

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

i want to select data from table users by inner join table users_role inner join table role with where clause but when i build the app an error accured

```
@Query(value = "select u from users u join users_role ur on u.id = ur.user_id join roles r on ur.role_id = r.id where r.role = 'ROLE_PL' ")
List<User> findPersonels();
```

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 8.287 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.backend.AuthentificationJwtApplicationTests
[ERROR] contextLoads(com.backend.AuthentificationJwtApplicationTests)  Time elapsed: 0.004 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personnelController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personnelRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.backend.repository.PersonnelRepository.findPersonels()!
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personnelRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.backend.repository.PersonnelRepository.findPersonels()!
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.backend.repository.PersonnelRepository.findPersonels()!
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: users is not mapped [select u from users u join users_role ur on u.id = ur.user_id join roles r on ur.role_id = r.id where r.role = 'ROLE_PL' ]
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: users is not mapped [select u from users u join users_role ur on u.id = ur.user_id join roles r on ur.role_id = r.id where r.role = 'ROLE_PL' ]
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: users is not mapped
```

Comment: Change `select u from` with `select u.* from`

Comment: well @forpas , i tried it directly in my database (sql) and it worked, but when i inserted it inside " Query ", it gives me an error about the the " * ", a changed it to u.id and then, gave me the same error " users is not mapped "

Comment: `Query` expects a **JPQL** query. JPQL is not SQL. It's a different language. It doesn't work with tables and column names, but with entities, their properties and their associations. Read the documentation to learn it: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems to be neither JPQL (`users` isn't an entity) nor SQL (you can't `select <table alias> from ...` in SQL).

Pick one of the two and if you pick SQL add a `nativeQuery=true` to the `@Query` annotation.